# Weird storage declaration from my computer

Tags: memory, storage

With no good reason I had a look at my computer's storage going on the `apple` and `About this Mac`. Here is the display:

[image]

The pink bar doesn't make much sense. It obviously does not represent the 80.67GB of free storage. Two sections correspond to pink; "Photos" and "Backups". I obviously don't have 140.76TB of backups. And probably not on this computer that has only 320GB of storage.

What is going on here?

Comment: I haven't tried to shut off and on my computer yet. I'll shut it off for the night and let you know the outcome tomorrow.

Comment: On my mac it also displays nonsense, like 253 GB for Applications (which is  impossible) but it shows no Backups section (on the time machine volume it shows it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would ignore it. That graph is particularly unreliable and it's unclear sometimes, even when it's showing storage that is possible within the computer, what exactly it is counting. If you want a better overview of your storage, use something like [DaisyDisk](http://daisydisk.com).

Answer (score 1):

tubedogg is likely right but I would be tempted to boot into recovery mode and run Disk Utility then repair disk and fix permissions. It **might** be the symptom of a disk issue that could be easily fixed.